# "Совершенно не имеет никакого отношения", а?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, порядок-слов

> Но совершенно не имеет никакого отношения ко всем моим длительным
>   умоприключениям…

Никакой - это **уже** "совершенно никакой"? Или что? Порядок слов мешает (восприятию)?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что одно из усилительных слов лишнее.

**Но  не имеет никакого отношения ко всем моим длительным умоприключениям…**

**Пояснение**

Можно не иметь никакого отношения (например, прямого или косвенного) ни к чему (указание предмета).

Но в заданном предложении предмет указан, а слова *совершенно* и **никакого** определяют вид отношения, поэтому достаточно одного слова.

Сравнить: Но ***совершенно никак*** не связано с моими умоприключениями... Здесь яснее видно, что слова повторяются.